# Moving Cell in TableView

Tags: swift, tableview

I want to moving cell (reordering cell) in `TableView`.

I have tried like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var editBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var tableData = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let itemToMove = tableData[sourceIndexPath.row]
        tableData.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        tableData.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    @IBAction func editBarButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.editing = !self.editing
    }
}
```

I have also set `TableViewDataSource` and `TableViewDelegate` in `Storyboard`.

But when I click on the `editBarButton`, It doesn't cause any affects.

I want to make it like this:

[image]

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found the answer. If I don't use `UITableViewController`, I need to implement this function:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

Because this function says:

> Sets whether the view controller shows an editable view. Subclasses
>   that use an edit-done button must override this method to change their
>   view to an editable state if editing is true and a non-editable state
>   if it is false. This method should invoke super’s implementation
>   before updating its view.

It works now.

Comment: Which is exactly what I mentioned at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataHolder: Array = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return dataHolder.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = dataHolder[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let itemToMove: String = dataHolder[fromIndexPath.row]
        dataHolder.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
        dataHolder.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    }

    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
}
```

If you're not using `UITableViewController` then ensure you've implemented the following method:

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: @khuong291 What doesn't work exactly? You need to be much more specific than "But it doesn't work".

Comment: When I click on the edit Bar Button. It doesn't cause any affects. Your code is implemented for UITableViewController. I have done like you, but not work.